# QPixmap не делает скрин окна веб браузера

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qimage

Когда я использую `QPixmap::GrabWindow(WId)` на окне с веб браузером (например, *Chrome*), он возвращает мне просто черный экран. Использую следующий код:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
m_pixmap = screen->grabWindow(hW);
m_image = m_pixmap.toImage();
m_image.save("p.png");
```

*p.png* - получается просто черная картинка. С другими окнами получается нормально (например, скрин проводника).
Как можно сделать скрин окна браузера?

Comment: навести английский SO, пусть там тоже валяется этот кусок кода, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55535047/7388307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что QScreen::grabWindow использует [Windows GDI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDI) для захвата картинки. Это достаточно древнее API, которое используют программы без аппаратного ускорения (рисуются процессором). А хром - ПО не древнее и уже давно рисуется средствами [Windows DXGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Graphics_Infrastructure).

Я уже писал ПО, которое использует эту технологию. Опубликовал пример кода [тут](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qt-dxgi-screenshot). Собирается компилятором MSVC на библиотеке Qt 5.10, вроде бы без разницы, 2015 или 2017. Моя машина 64 битная, возможно это тоже важно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри два класса: FrameBroadcast и FrameCapturer. FrameBroadcast запрашивает скриншот с некоторым временным интервалом из FrameCapturer и через сигнал `void frameCaptured(QSharedPointer<Frame> frame);` рассылает подписчикам. QSharedPointer автоматически удаляет память, выделенную под содержимое экрана, как только выходит из области видимости всех обработчиков слота.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>

#include "framebroadcast.h"

/*static Frame* CopyFrame(const Frame *incomingFrame)
{
    Frame *frame = new Frame();
    frame->width=incomingFrame->width;
    frame->height=incomingFrame->height;
    frame->lenght=incomingFrame->lenght;
    frame->buffer=new unsigned char[frame->lenght];

    std::memcpy(frame->buffer,incomingFrame->buffer,frame->lenght);
    return frame;
}

static Frame* CopyFrame(const QSharedPointer<Frame> &incomingFrame)
{
    return CopyFrame(incomingFrame.data());
}*/


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(dialog);

    FrameBroadcast *cast = new FrameBroadcast();
    QObject::connect(cast, &FrameBroadcast::frameCaptured, [=](const QSharedPointer<Frame> &frame) {

        int w = static_cast<int>(frame.data()->width);
        int h = static_cast<int>(frame.data()->height);

        QImage img(frame.data()->buffer,w,h,QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
        label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
        label->resize(w,h);

        qDebug() << "Update";
    });
    cast->startCapture();

    dialog->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

В main.cpp создается простенькое диалоговое окно, на которое выводится результат захвата. На всякий случай я приложил код, который отвязывает содержимое экрана от QSharedPointer, если разместить все манипуляции в одном слоте не удастся. Он сразу после инклудов и закомментирован.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"D3D11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Shcore.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"windowscodecs.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxguid.lib")
```

Детально разбирать код нет смысла. Он слишком большой, но переоборудовать под свои нужды труда не составит. Примечательно, что используется "[Автосвязывание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)" - фишка компилятора Microsoft: необходимые библиотеки сами подтянутся на этапе компиляции (загляните в framecapturer.h)